# node js not responding to query

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js

I have created a web app that is supposed to respond to a request by sending the request body back. This is the ajax code:

```
    $(function() {
    // Get the form.
    var form = $('#ajax-contact');

    // Get the messages div.
    var formMessages = $('#form-messages');
    console.log(formMessages);
    $(form).submit(function(event) {
        // Stop the browser from submitting the form.
        event.preventDefault();
        var formData = $(form).serialize();
        $.ajax({
           type: 'POST',
            url: "/contact.html",
            data: formData
    });});});
```

This is my code to respond to the request:

```
    app.use('/contact.html', function(req, res,err){
        if(err){
             console.log(err.message);
        };
        console.log("it arrived");
        console.log(req.body);
        res.send('POST Data: '+JSON.stringify(req.body));
    });
```

When I try this, I get an error 304 and no output to the console. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Please show the complete code.

Comment: You are normally routing to a route, not a file name, `/contact` for example. 304 means "not modified" - I never tried to send an ajax request to a file, but I believe that this will be the "error", as jquery might try to pick the file.

Comment: Do those 2 `console.log()`'s from `app.use()` run in your terminal? If those don't run, that means the function isn't running at all. Especially since you're not getting an error.

Comment: Also, even if the ajax call would succeed, you would simply ignore the result as you do nothing with it

Comment: console.log does work, I tried using /contact and I got the same result